# Spire.PDF prints pdf only in grayscale

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I am using the free version of Spire.PDF to print a local pdf file but the print is in grayscale even though the pdf file is in color. Here is my code

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        doc.LoadFromFile(fileName);
        doc.ColorSpace = PdfColorSpace.RGB;
        PrintDialog dialogPrint = new PrintDialog();
        dialogPrint.AllowPrintToFile = true;
        dialogPrint.AllowSomePages = true;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = doc.Pages.Count;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.Pages.Count;

        if (dialogPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the start page to print
            doc.PrintFromPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
            //Set the pagenumber which you choose as the final page to print
            doc.PrintToPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
            //Set the name of the printer which is to print the PDF
            doc.PrinterName = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument;

            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Color = true;
            dialogPrint.Document = printDoc;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
```

I have checked `dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.SupportsColor` returns true

Comment: [This](https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/support-duplex-an-color-print-t6786.html) says to try true/false for `printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.Color`

Comment: I've already tried that in the code above

Comment: I would suggest you first try the commercial version, if it works well, then it might be a bug in the free version.